# How to add all the values in the JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

Here I am fetching the JSON data from the API using an AJAX call. Now I need to add all the visits.Here is what I have done. Can anyone suggest me how to do.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
  {
var X = [];
var Y = [];
var data = [];
function loadJSON(callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/nihnp', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    }
     xobj.send(null);
}
var sum = 0;
loadJSON(function(response) {
    var response;
    response = $.parseJSON(response);
   
$(function () {
    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
       sum += parseFloat(item.total_visits);
        
    });
   document.write(sum);   
}); 
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> Total visists </h1>
```

Comment: you haven't said what the problem is with your current code.

Comment: Is parsing the JSON the issue? Without knowing the JSON structure this cannot be answered.

Comment: `$.each(response.testcompany.dates, function (i, item) {  sum += parseFloat(item.visits); });`   ps.  I get `35`, is that what you was after?

Answer (score 0):

In your code document.write method is override whole document. you have to just override value of any one tag of html. Here I have just added span tag for write dynamic value in h1 tag

```js
$(document).ready(function()
  {
var X = [];
var Y = [];
var data = [];
function loadJSON(callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/zlms5', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    }
     xobj.send(null);
}
var sum = 0;
loadJSON(function(response) {
    var response;
    response = $.parseJSON(response);
   
$(function () {
    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
       if(typeof item.total_visits !== "undefined")
       {
           sum += parseFloat(item.total_visits);
       }
        
    });
   $("#total_visits").text(sum);   
}); 
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> Total visists : <span id="total_visits"></span></h1>
```

Comment: when I try the same with another API its showing "NaN". Because some total_visits are specified as "not_available". Is there any other way to overcome that?

Comment: I have added condition of total_visits is exist or not

Comment: Now can you check the above script.